# Laravel Blade template checkbox checked when another one is checked

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have the following checkboxes in view

```
<div class="form-group"> 
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Roles</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4"> 
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>             
                <input type="checkbox" name="data_entry"> Data Entry <br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="save_on_ext_hd"> Save On External HD      <br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="print"> Print   <br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="export_csv">Export CSV   <br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete"> Delete
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using laravel 5 and blade template.

the issue is: when click on any checkbox the first one checked and verse versa

Ex: when click pn print checkbox the data_entry checked automatically and when unchecked print data_entry unchecked.

also when check print data_entry checked and when check delete for example data_entry unchecked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because all your checkboxes are inside one `<label>`. Labels with an input inside activate the input when clicked. So clicking anywhere inside the label will trigger all checkboxes.

Solve this by giving each its own `<label>`:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="data_entry"> Data Entry <br />
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="save_on_ext_hd"> Save On External HD<br />
</label>
<!-- etc -->
```